# PHP Import large CSV file into MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv, pdo

I need to run a daily cron job that iterates over a 6 MB CSV file to insert each of the ~10,000 entries into a MySQL table. The code I have written hangs and produces a timeout after a while.

```
if (($handle = fopen($localCSV, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $dbdata = array(
            'SiteID' => $siteID,
            'TimeStamp' => $data[0],
            'ProductID' => $data[1],
            'CoordX' => $data[2],
            'CoordY' => $data[3]
        );  
        $row++;
        $STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO temp_csv (SiteID,TimeStamp,ProductID,CoordX,CoordY) VALUES (:SiteID,:TimeStamp,:ProductID,:CoordX,:CoordY)");
        $STH->execute($dbdata);
    }
    fclose($handle);
    echo $row." rows inserted.";
}
```

It would have been ideal to use `mysql_*` functions instead of PDO, so I could implode the values into one single query (although huge) but unfortunately I need to comply with some guidelines (PDO to be strictly used).

I searched SO and there are very similar questions but none could solve mine. What I tried is the following:

1- Ran `LOAD DATA INFILE` and `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` queries but kept getting "file not found" errors although the file is definitely there with 777 permissions. The DB server and the shared hosting account are in different environments. I tried relative and url paths to the csv file but no luck (couldn't find the file in both cases).

2- I split the csv file into 2 files and ran the script on each, to see the threshold at which the script hangs, but it inserted the entries twice in the table in the case of each file.

I don't have access to `php.ini` since it's a shared hosting account (cloudsites) and only access to `MySQL` through phpMyAdmin.

What else can I try to accomplish this as efficiently as possible?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I deal with .csv -> mysql frequently, and my general strategy is to do multiple records per insert, e.g. INSERT INTO table VALUES (one, two), (three, four), (five, six), etc.

Comment: Doing a batch insert is going to be better instead of a single insert per row.

Comment: Thanks @Dave, but how can I do that with PDO in the while loop? It would have worked with `mysql_*` but I can't use it.

Comment: here is a good post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176352/pdo-prepared-inserts-multiple-rows-in-single-query

Comment: Move `$DBH->prepare` call outside the cycle.

Comment: Thanks @user602525. Didn't see that and will give it a try.

Comment: Also a few suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3908669/1580288 (turn off autocommit).

Comment: @Skpd, I moved it out of the loop but it didn't have any effect. The script still times out.

Comment: Peronsally, I'd scrap this question and ask another one on how to get `LOAD DATA` to work.

Comment: @EthanB, I saw those and they all suggest LOAD DATA which I have tried and it didn't work

Comment: @NinoKay can you describe the environment you're in more? I'm assuming you aren't able to ssh into these machines?

Comment: @user602525 no I can't SSH into them (Rackspace Cloudsites)...

Comment: @NinoKay, They also suggest turning off autocommit (aka using explicit transactions).

Comment: The only viable and stable solution is to split the load process into more than one step & have your cron run more often or create more crons.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks not wrong to me. It hangs because it just takes a while to execute. You should use phps [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) to prevent timeouts.

```
if (($handle = fopen($localCSV, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    set_time_limit(30) // choose a value that works for you
    // ... the rest of your script
```

Better, however would be to start a background-process where the csv is processed, it would need some sort of locking, so it doesn't run in multiple instances in parallel. If you'd write the status into a file on disk you could present it easily to your users.
The same applies for a cron script (if you can do that with your hosting solution)

The use of PDO looks ok to me. I wouldn't think of inserting all rows of the csv at once, but you could insert multiple rows at once with PDO, too. Create the statement and the data array for multiple rows. It could look like this rough sketch (I did not execute it so there will probably be some errors):

```
function insert_data($DBH, array $dbdata, array $values) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO temp_csv (SiteID,TimeStamp,ProductID,CoordX,CoordY) VALUES %1$s;";
    $STH = $DBH->prepare(sprintf($sql, join(', ', $values)));
    $STH->execute($dbdata);
}

if (($handle = fopen($localCSV, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $dbdata = array();
    $values = array();
    $row = 0;
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if(!count($dbdata))
            $dbdata['SiteID'] = $siteID;

        $dbdata['TimeStamp_'.$row] = $data[0];
        $dbdata['ProductID_'.$row] = $data[1];
        $dbdata['CoordX_'.$row] = $data[2];
        $dbdata['CoordY_'.$row] = $data[3];
        $values[] = sprintf('(:SiteID_%1$s,:TimeStamp_%1$s,:ProductID_%1$s,:CoordX_%1$s,:CoordY_%1$s)', $row);
        $row++;

        if($row % 10 === 0) {
            set_time_limit(30);
            insert_data($DBH, $dbdata, $values);
            $values = array();
            $dbdata = array();
        }
    }
    // insert the rest
    if(count($values))
        insert_data($DBH, $dbdata, $values);
    fclose($handle);
    echo $row." rows inserted.";
}
```

The shortcut to at least read the php.ini configurations is [phpinfo](http://www.php.net/function.phpinfo). Look into the PHP manual, a lot of the config values can be set at runtime from your code.

Comment: Regular server can insert at least 1k records / sec. Increasing time limit and still doing things wrong is not a valid solution.