# Large CSV file import to mysql, best practice

Tags: php, csv, mysqli

Looking for insight on the best approach for large csv file imports to mysql and managing the dataset. This is for an ecommerce storefront "startup". All product data will be read from csv files which are download via curl (server to server).

Each csv file represents a different supplier/warehouse with up to 100,000 products. In total there are roughly 1.2 million products spread over 90-100 suppliers. At least 75% of the row data (51 columns) is redundant garbage and will not be needed.

Would it be better to use mysqli LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE to 'temp_products' table. Then, make the needed data adjustments per row, then insert to the live 'products' table or simply use fgetcsv() and go row by row? The import will be handled by a CronJob using the sites php.ini with a memory limit of 128M.

- Apache V2.2.29
- PHP V5.4.43
- MySQL V5.5.42-37.1-log
- memory_limit 128M

I'm not looking for "How to's". I'm simply looking for the "best approach" from the communities perspective and experience.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to import CSV file to MySQL table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635166/how-to-import-csv-file-to-mysql-table)

Comment: I know how to import. What method from the ones listed would be the better route given the specifics of my question?

Comment: maybe interesting? [Need Time-Efficient Method of Importing Large CSV File Via PHP Into Multiple MySQL Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908477/need-time-efficient-method-of-importing-large-csv-file-via-php-into-multiple-mys)

Comment: @Ryan Vincent thanks. Good info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have direct experience of doing something virtually identical to what you describe -- lots of third party data sources in different formats all needing to go into a single master table.

I needed to take different approaches for different data sources, because some were in XML, some in CSV, some large, some small, etc. For the large CSV ones, I did indeed follow roughly your suggested routed:

- I used `LOAD DATA INFILE` to dump the raw contents into a temporary table.
- I took the opportunity to transform or discard some of the data within this query; `LOAD DATA INFILE` allows some quite complex queries. This allowed me to use the same temp table for several of the import processes even though they had quite different CSV data, which made the next step easier.
- I then used a set of secondary SQL queries to pull the temp data into the various main tables. All told, I had about seven steps to the process.

I had a set of PHP classes to do the imports, which all implemented a common interface. This meant that I could have a common front-end program which could run any of the importers.

Since a lot of the importers did similar tasks, I put the commonly used code in traits so that the code could be shared.

Some thoughts based on the things you said in your question:

- `LOAD DATA INFILE` will be orders of magnitude quicker than `fgetcsv()` with a PHP loop.
- `LOAD DATA INFILE` queries can be very complex and achieve very good data mapping without ever having to run any other code, as long as the imported data is going into a single table.
- Your memory limit is likely to need to be raised. However, using `LOAD DATA INFILE` means that it will be MySQL which will use the memory, not PHP, so the PHP limit won't come into play for that. 128M is still likely to be too low for you though.
  -If you struggle to import the whole thing in one go, try using some simple Linux shell commands to split the file into several smaller chunks. CSV data format should make that fairly simple.

Comment: Thanks @Spudley for the feedback. With all the data transformation, manipulation etc I wanted to get some feedback before jumping in head first. I'm forced at least with startup to have this running on a shared hosting account (Bluehost). I'm leaning toward LOAD DATA INFILE to a temp and using a CronJob that runs every 15 minutes to handle porting to live. This should give me some control over server load and memory management. Every few ports to live check resources and exit() if I need to.